# Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" - Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to give permission to change the User-Agent header with a chrome extension using XMLHttpRequest?

I tried to use webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders, but it doesn't trigger for XMLHttpRequests, which is also mentioned here
[Chrome extension: webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders behaves strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986077/chrome-extension-webrequest-onbeforesendheaders-behaves-strange)

Sorry if this question was duplicated somewhere else, I'm unable to find any solution though.