# Firefox extension dev: howto fix wrong "Referer" in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, http-referer

I am trying to program a simple Firefox (66.0 Quantum) Extension intended to download complete HLS video streams. The basic approach is to start video-playback using the page's regular UI functionality and to intercept the loading of respective HLS .m3u8-playlist files from within the extension's background-script (i.e. using "browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest"). The extension similarily also intercepts the first "video-chunk" request triggered by the playlist (using "browser.webRequest.onSendHeaders") - so it knowns what the correct http-headers for respective "video-chunk" requests would need to look like.

permission-wise I am currently using these:

> ```
>   "permissions": [
>     "downloads", "activeTab", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"
>   ],
> ```

Based on the above collected information, ideally the extension should be able to create correct XMLHttpRequest requests for all the "movie-chucks" found in the playlist and to ultimately download all those files. Obviously a respective long running "download" task should be performed in the background-script and once the above information has been collected there should be no need to still keep the original browser tab open.

Problem: Some of the servers that serve the movie-chunks apparently rely on the "Referer" (and maybe "Origin") header for some kind of access-control and the XMLHttpRequest instances created from within the background-script DO NOT allow to create the respective correct header (since it is a restricted field it cannot be manually set to the correct value).

The only workaround that I found so far leaves a lot to be desired: A content.XMLHttpRequest created within a content-script uses the correct headers and my background-script can delegate (via messaging) the respective file loading to the content-script (which is rather silly and means that the background-script process will fail if the original browser tab is closed during download).

Is there any way that allows to properly do/complete all the download logic on the background-script side (even after the originating browser tab has been closed)?

Comment: Those headers can be easily spoofed (a [random example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071136)) in webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders listener.

Comment: bingo! thx @wOxxOm it works like a charm :-)